# Error when trying to get Azure Kubernetes Service to use Cluster Load balancer from Service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-aks, streamsets

I'm working to get Streamsets Data Collector running in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and when I run `kubectl ....` the service appears to be up, however its giving this error.  This is an RBAC AKS Cluster so I think I need to give the service principal permissions AND/OR do a cluster role binding to that service in Kubernetes.  Any ideas?

[image: Kubernetes Error]
[image: SDC Service]

Answer (score 0):

The error shows invalid client. It probably means that the original service principal secret of your AKS cluster is invalid or expired. See the similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985568/how-can-i-find-the-service-principal-secret-of-my-aks-cluster/51996895#51996895).

Follow that link, you can find the original client secret when you deploy the AKS cluster, so that you can re-add that as a key to the Service Principal. On the master and node VMs in the Kubernetes cluster, the service principal credentials are stored in the file `/etc/kubernetes/azure.json`.

On the VM page---Run command---choose RunShellScript---Enter `cat /etc/kubernetes/azure.json` and click "Run" then you could find the property `aadClientSecret`.

For more details, you could read [Service principals with Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal)